# Can we use spark.sql on any other database tables other than Hive tables?

Tags: dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql, cloud, sql-data-warehouse

Currently our databases are hosted in other databases . We are thinking to execute the process in SPARK by using JDBC connectors. Is it possible to use SPARK.SQL statements after we connect the datasource or do we have to load the data to hive to use spark.sql query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on Spark tables.

With push-down you can use against JDBC sources and HBASE etc. but then you may as well for JDBC sources use the SQL there for functionality and it runs on that hardware. Mostly you bring lower volume of data in to combine in Spark with Big Data sources and write less data to JDBC RDBMS's.